# read pmml using sklearn2pmml?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pmml

I was using `sklearn2pmml` to export my model to `.pmml` file.

How to read the PMML file back to python PMMLpipeline ?

I was checking the repo but could not find the solution in the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to save a fitted Scikit-Learn pipeline so that it could be loaded back into Scikit-Learn/Python, then you need to use "native" Python serialization libraries and dataformats such as Pickle.

The conversion from Scikit-Learn to PMML should be regarded one-way operation. There is no easy way of getting PMML back into Scikit-Learn.

You can always save the fitted Scikit-Learn pipeline in multiple data formats. Save one copy in Pickle data format so that it could be loaded back into Scikit-Learn/Python, and save another copy in PMML data format so that it would be loaded in non-Python environments.

Comment: I'd also recommend joblib if you have more data.